# understanding the return type of anonymous function lambda

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how can lambda function be used.

```
def adder_func(a, b):
    return a + b


print(adder_func(4, 5))

# trying with lambda
print(list(lambda a, b: a + b))
```

When trying to use lambda as a adder_function, why is that the result cannot be printed?

O/P:

```
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\redsuren\PycharmProjects\py_charm_tutorial_amigoscode\lambda_adder.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(list(lambda a, b: a + b))
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

AND,
If keyword "list"  is removed and try to print the return value, it give me some hexa_value, what does this value represent?

```
print(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

O/P:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x0000019440B5E0D0>
```

Comment: What output did you expect `list(lambda a, b: a + b))` to return?

Comment: You use a `lambda` function in the same way you use any other function. You call it. With the right number and type of parameters of course.

Comment: You'd get the exact same behavior if you replaced the lambda with `adder_func`. Do `print(list(adder_func))` and `print(adder_func)` do what you would expect?

Comment: Try `print((lambda a, b: a + b)(4, 5))` vs `print((adder_func)(4, 5))` vs `print(adder_func(4, 5))`

Comment: Side note: `list` is not a keyword, it's a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).  So is `print` for that matter. They're just global variables that are available by default (to a first approximation anyway). There's nothing stopping you from using those names in other contexts (other than personal sanity), unlike true keywords like `if` or `def`.

Comment: @yeputons this worked  
print((lambda a, b: a + b)(4, 5))

how does this differ?:
a = 4
b = 5
print(lambda a, b: a + b)

Comment: You use a `lambda` function in the same way you use any other function. You call it. With the right number and type of parameters. Also like a function you can't directly set variables that are inside the scope of a function. That is, code like this also works: `x = 4; y = 5; print((lambda a, b: a + b)(x, y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to do this

```
adder_func = lambda a, b: a + b
print(adder_func(4, 5))
```

Or this, which defines the function, then passes the parameters on the same line... You don't need `list()` to do that

```
a = 4
b = 5
print((lambda a, b: a + b)(a, b))
```

Printing a function object isn't all that useful, as you can see, and the `list()` function accepts iterables, which function objects are not (not to be confused with the return values of functions that are iterable, or generator objects), for example

```
def adder_func(a, b):
    yield a + b
print(adder_func)  # <function adder_func at 0x1019c3b80>
print(adder_func(4, 5))  # <generator object adder_func at 0x101996200>
print(list(adder_func(4, 5)))  # [9]
```

Comment: I am expecting to print the result by just using lambda:

a = 4
b = 5
print(lambda a, b: a + b)