# how are the 2 implementation of lambda different

Tags: python

```
z = (lambda *a: a, (1,2))
print(z)

k = (lambda *a: a)(1,2)
print(k)
```

How does the comma (`,`) and parenthesis work here in lambda implementation?

Output:

```
(<function <lambda> at 0x000002648500E0D0>, (1, 2))
(1, 2)
```

If I remove the comma and give parenthesis I get the desired output (1,2).
However, if I give the comma it gives me function ... and (1,2).

Please make me understand.

Comment: One is a `tuple` with a `lamda` and `tuple`, the other is generating a `lamba` and executing it

Comment: @Wondercricket I am sorry, I did not understand which is which..

Comment: Try `print(type(z))`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expected the comma to do? Or you'd written it accidentally?

Comment: `z` is a tuple with two elements: one is `lambda *a: a` and the other is `(1,2)`. `k` is the result of calling the `(lambda *a: a)` function with `(1,2)` as the arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the lambda ‘z’, because you don’t call the lambda you created (append a pair of parentheses and pass the parameters), so, it is just a lambda that returns a tuple which contains unpacked a and (1, 2).

In the lambda ‘k’, because you called the lambda you created, and you passed the parameter 1 and 2, so, according to the lambda, it returns an unpacked tuple (when 1 and 2 passed to the lambda, however, the parameter becomes (1, 2) ).
Because the lambda returns (1, 2), the variable ‘k’ was assigned with the returned value.

Comment: Rectify a wrong, z is a tuple, you can check it with type(). Because when z is being to an AST, z will be split into two parts: the lambda and the tuple (1, 2)

Answer (score 3):

First case;

```
z = (lambda *a: a, (1,2))
print(z)
```

Here `z` is a tuple which has two elements, `lambda *a: a` and another tuple `(1, 2)`. When you print it, you will simply get these elements printed, ie, a function and a tuple;

```
 (<function <lambda> at 0x000002648500E0D0>, (1, 2))
```

Another case;

```
k = (lambda *a: a)(1,2)
print(k)
```

Here you are creating a lambda function and to call the function, we add parenthesis at the end of the function and pass the parameters. That is what you are doing here.

By adding `(1, 2)` at the end of the lambda function calls it with 1 and 2 as parameters.

Also note that `*` before `a` in the lambda function (if you don't know). It means that spread the given list or tuple.

Answer (score 2):

> If  I remove the comma... I get the desired output

So, your *desired action* is to invoke the lambda function

You don't execute functions using commas, in other words commas never exist between their names/definitions and their parameters, so if you'd expected that to work, it'd be a typo

Now, that all being said, your first line is functionally equivalent to

```
z=((lambda *a: a), (1,2), )
```

Which, hopefully makes it a little clearer that you've defined a tuple of two things, a function object and the tuple `(1,2)`

Regarding the output, as shown before, you're just printing a lambda - [understanding the return type of anonymous function lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836136/understanding-the-return-type-of-anonymous-function-lambda)